# org.java_websocket.client.websocketClient 1.3.0 close() method doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, websocket, webapi, java-websocket

Current Problem

I created a program that uses a web socket to get data.
The connection to the server at the connection destination was lost, but the connection was not determined.

To terminate the connection if the last message received exceeds a certain time
supported by 1.3.0 version of org.java_websocket.client.websocketClient
I was use Close() method , but it remains close_wait.
Find another solution and use the WebsocketClient.getConnection().close(CloseFrame.ABNORMAL_CLOSE) but keep it close_wait as well

It must be resolved in version 1.3.0

Another solution is required.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I solved it.
In order to check whether the websocket is closed or not, the websocket status was continuously expressed by a thread even after closing, so it was expressed as closed_wait.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
In order to check whether the websocket is closed or not, the websocket status was continuously expressed by a thread even after closing, so it was expressed as closed_wait.